# WordPress 5.9.3 - Attempt to read property "ID" on int in [...]/post-thumbnail-template.php on line 116

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a template part in a custom theme and all I'm doing is a WordPress query and in the loop displaying the post thumbnail.

```
<?php $posts = $args['posts'];

$q_args = [
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post__in' => $posts
];

$posts_query = new WP_Query($q_args);
if( $posts_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
  <div class="posts-grid">
    <?php while( $posts_query->have_posts() ) {
      $posts_query->the_post();
      $post_id = get_the_ID(); ?>
      <div class="post-container">
        <a class="post" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
          <div class="post-content">
            <?= get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'blog-thumbnail') ?>
            <?= get_the_date('d M Y'); ?>
            <?php the_title('<h3>', '</h3>'); ?>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    <?php }
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

When I go to view the page the loop shows, and everything pulls through correctly, however I get an alert before the thumbnail image

```
Warning: Attempt to read property "ID" on int in /wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php on line 116
```

Looking at line 116 in that file it's part of the update_post_thumbnail_cache function

```
function update_post_thumbnail_cache( $wp_query = null ) {
    if ( ! $wp_query ) {
        $wp_query = $GLOBALS['wp_query'];
    }

    if ( $wp_query->thumbnails_cached ) {
        return;
    }

    $thumb_ids = array();

    foreach ( $wp_query->posts as $post ) {
        $id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
        if ( $id ) {
            $thumb_ids[] = $id;
        }
    }

    if ( ! empty( $thumb_ids ) ) {
        _prime_post_caches( $thumb_ids, false, true );
    }

    $wp_query->thumbnails_cached = true;
}
```

I thought at first it was that because I was passing the post ID to get_the_post_thumbnail, but if I change that to passing the post object I still get the same warning. Can anyone share with me what I've done to cause this warning?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of head scratching around this I ended up going in a different direction. Instead of using get_the_post_thumbnail() I opted to get the ID of the post thumbnail ( using get_post_thumbnail_id() ) and then using wp_get_attachment_image() to output it and this removed the error.

```
<?php $posts = $args['posts'];

$q_args = [
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post__in' => $posts
];

$posts_query = new WP_Query($q_args);
if( $posts_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
  <div class="posts-grid">
    <?php while( $posts_query->have_posts() ) {
      $posts_query->the_post();
      $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id (); ?>
      <div class="post-container">
        <a class="post" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
          <div class="post-content">
            <?= wp_get_attachment_image($thumbnail_id, 'blog-thumbnail') ?>
            <?= get_the_date('d M Y'); ?>
            <?php the_title('<h3>', '</h3>'); ?>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    <?php }
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

This isn't the most optimal solution as you are creating extra database calls running get_post_thumbnail_id and wp_get_attachment_image but it works.